# Different type of way to store Database

Tags: magento-1.9, database, model

I am using in this way to store Database

```
$connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                        $connectionWrite = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_write');
                        $query = "insert into imguplaod "
                                         . "(img) values "
                                         . "(:img)";
                        $binds = array('img_url'=> $img);
                        $connectionWrite->query($query, $binds);
```

But i didn't see any custom module use this way, Can you please tell me what are the way to store Database into values.

Answer (score 1):

for that you have to create model for that. how to create model follow this 
http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/04/creating-a-magento-custom-model/

, we will create a custom model that uses a different name than the Module name. The Module tree will look like as shown in below:

```
-Pixafy/
    -Block/
    -controllers/
    -Model/
        -Resource/
            -Custommodel/
                -Collection.php
            -Custommodel.php
        -Custommodel.php
    -etc/
        -config.xml
    -sql/
```

In config.xml, we will set up our custom Model configuration. There are three things that we need to setup for a Model in the config.xml. 1. Enable Models in our Module. 2. Enable Model resources in our Module. 3. Add an entity table to our Model Resource.

```
<models>
    <pixafy>
        <class>[Frontname]_Pixafy_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>pixafy_resource</resourceModel>
    </pixafy>
</models>
```

The  tag is our Group name and should match our module name. The  tag is the Base name or Class prefix, that tells all models in the pixafy group where to look for the actual model objects. [Frontname]_Pixafy_Model is equivalent to Frontname/Pixafy/Model which is the path all our models. The  tag indicates which Resource Model that Pixafy group Model should use. We will have to create the  configure the resource object that is in `Pixafy/Model/Resource/Custommodel.php`.

```
<models>
    <pixafy>
        <class>[Frontname]_Pixafy_Model</class>
                      <resourceModel>pixafy_resource</resourceModel>
    </pixafy>

     <pixafy_resource>
        <class>[Frontname]_Pixafy_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <custommodel>
                            <table>[table_name_in_database]</table>
                        </ custommodel >
        </entities>
    </pixafy_resource>
</models>
```

The resource model  contains the configuration that communicates with our database. Again, we specified where the resource is located in  tag. The  section tells Customemodel.php in the resource which table in the Database to connect to.

Now we have finished with Config.xml. We then have to create the Model class and Resource class. `Pixafy/Model/Custommodel.php` will contain the following code:

```
class Frontname_Pixafy_Model_Custommodel extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('pixafy/custommodel');
    }
}
```

All basic Models that interact with the database should extend the Mage_Core_Model_Abstract class. This abstract class forces you to implement a single method named _construct (NOTE: this is not PHP’s constructor__construct). This method should call the class’s _init method with the same identifying URI you’ll be using in the Mage::getModel method call.

`Pixafy/Model/Resource/Custommodel.php` will contain the following code:

```
class Frontname_Pixafy_Model_Resource_Custommodel extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('pixafy/custommodel', 'custommodel_id');
    }
}
```

Again, the first parameter of the init method is the URL used to identify the Model. The second parameter is the database field that uniquely identifies any particular column. In most cases, this should be the primary key.

So, having a single Model is useful, but sometimes we want to grab a list of Models. Rather than returning a simple array of Models, each Magento Model type has a unique collection object associated with it. These objects implement the PHP IteratorAggregate and Countable interfaces, which means they can be passed to the countfunction, and used in for each constructs. Let’s create the Collection class.

`Pixafy/Model/Resource/Custommodel/Collection.php` should contain the following code:

```
class Frontname_Pixafy_Model_Resource_Custommodel_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract {
    protected function _construct()
    {
            $this->_init('pixafy/custommodel');
    }
}
```

And that’s it; our model is ready to be used. Let’s test our model by calling model:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('pixafy/custommodel');
```

To query a collection, we will call:

```
$collections = Mage::getModel('pixafy/custommodel')->getCollection();
```

**for saving in database through model**

```
 $savemodel = Mage::getModel('pixafy/custommodel'); 
 $savemodel->setImg($img);
 $savemodel->save();
```

Comment: For all value store this way $savemodel->setImg($img); separately

Comment: yes you can set values like that `$savemodel->setYoucolumname($img);`

Comment: Okay thanks for your information i will check

Comment: it's for Frontname name which we written under config.xml right

Comment: sorry don't get you?

Comment: Okay leave it i got it